# Javascript - slicing a file - need to modify javascript

Tags: javascript, file, slice

I am new to javascripting and I have this piece of code. In this code, you can choose a file and then view it's first A-B bytes, B-C bytes, or the whole file.
Demonstration of this code at: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/  -  tittle: SLICING A FILE.

1. Question: How can I set a permanent file to be used in this script, instead of opportunity of uploading a random file? (for example, I have the file test.html, and I want it to be the only one file being used by this script).
2. Question: When I upload a html file, the script doesn't show a partial CONTENT of that file, but it shows the part of the SOURCE CODE of that file. For example, if the uploaded file contains an image tag , in the result I do not see the picture, but only the exactly rewritten source code. Is there any way how javascript results will act like normal page written in html?

Maybe this are primitive questions for someone skilled in this, but my programming knowledge ends with klowledge of C language and when I am learning to php or javascript, I am just guessing. Most of the times I am succesfull, but not now :(

Thanx for each answer!

```
<style>
  #byte_content {
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  #byte_range { margin-top: 5px; }
</style>

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button data-startbyte="0" data-endbyte="4">1-5</button>
  <button data-startbyte="5" data-endbyte="14">6-15</button>
  <button data-startbyte="6" data-endbyte="7">7-8</button>
  <button>entire file</button>
</span>
<div id="byte_range"></div>
<div id="byte_content"></div>

<script>
  function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('Please select a file!');
      return;
    }

    var file = files[0];
    var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
    var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
        document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent = 
            ['Read bytes: ', start + 1, ' - ', stop + 1,
             ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'].join('');
      }
    };

    var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
  }

  document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
      var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
      var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
      readBlob(startByte, endByte);
    }
  }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: you can't read file from disk without user interaction even with new File Api, so it is impossible to make "default" file choice

Comment: If you provide the file yourself then just Ajax it in and show htmlfragments from it

Answer (score 1):

1. No.  For security reasons, you cannot interact directly with the file system without the      user making a choice.  Imagine someone doing `upload 'known/path/to/passwords'`.
2. This is confused.  The **contents** and **source code** of a file are distinct ideas.  You're mixing levels.  A document has contents.  And a document might be represented by source code in a file.  But you do not upload a document.  You upload a file, that is, the set of bytes representing that source code.  Any interpretation of that as a document is a separate job you would need to perform.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: How can I set a permanent file to be used in this script, instead of opportunity of uploading a random file?

You can't access any files from the user's computer without him explicitly "uploading" them. Anything else would be security issue. However, some "apps" (browser extensions etc) can have this privilege, and in some browsers you can disable security.

To load a specific file everytime, you should use an ajax request out into the web.

> Question: When I upload a html file, the script doesn't show a partial CONTENT of that file, but it shows the part of the SOURCE CODE of that file.

That's how it should work. The html file consists only of the markup; the picture is a different file.

> Is there any way how javascript results will act like normal page written in html?

Of course you can render the HTML source by writing it into an iframe or something. Yet it will not access the image that is a local file.